# What is the best way create user from guest user in magento 2

Tags: magento2

I want to convert the guest user to the customer when guest user places the order.

Comment: Can you explain more details? Give an example. It's not clear.

Comment: For example, order confirmation email sent to the customer which is the guest user that guest user clicks on login link then after click on that link user automatically converted to the guest user to customer.

Comment: another way is obeserver after placed order crate new user programatically.

Comment: Could you edit your question with more details?

Comment: In default magento 2 there is a Create an account button is already available on success page when guest user placed an order.

Comment: yes, you are right but I need to create the user automatically after placing the success full order. without click on link

Answer (score 0):

create events.xml in your module etc :

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
          <event name="sales_order_place_after">
             <observer name="customer_create_observer" instance="VendorName\ModuleName\Observer\CustomerCreate" />
          </event>
      </config>
```

create CustomerCreate.php file in observer

```
class CustomerCreate implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
{
private $delegateService;

/**
 * @var Session
 */
private $session;

/**
 * @param Context $context
 * @param OrderCustomerDelegateInterface $customerDelegation
 * @param Session $session
 */
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Sales\Api\OrderCustomerDelegateInterface $customerDelegation,
    \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session
) {
    $this->delegateService = $customerDelegation;
    $this->session = $session;
}

    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
     $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
     $orderId = $order->getId();    
     $this->delegateService->delegateNew((int)$orderId);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Birjit, Sneha's solution would work for you, please give a try to it :)

Comment: $orderId = $order->getId();  not found

Comment: @himmat sales_order_place_after in this observer we can't get $order->getId() beacause  that time order is not saved.

Comment: I hope "sales_order_save_after" would be the right event to observe in that case :)